# How to return data from functions in function

Tags: jquery

I have this function. But how can I get data from my 2 txt file functions?
I want to have the tho Tabt values out in my alerts.

```
        function getWeight(){

            var fileKevin = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/mytextfile1.txt";
            var fileHeidi = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/mytextfile1.txt";


            //GET DATA FOR KEVIN
            $.get(fileKevin,function(txt){
                var lines = txt.split("\n");

                var total = parseInt(lines.length)
                var first = parseInt(0)
                var last = parseInt(total-1)
                var prev = parseInt(total-2)

                var NuVaegt =  (splitWeight(lines[last],1))
                var StartVaegt = splitWeight(lines[first],1);
                var ForrigeVaegt = splitWeight(lines[prev],1)
                var Tabt = decimal((NuVaegt-StartVaegt),1)
                var Sidst = decimal((NuVaegt-ForrigeVaegt),1)
                return Tabt;
            });

            //GET DATA FOR HEIDI
            $.get(fileHeidi,function(txt){
                var lines = txt.split("\n");

                var total = parseInt(lines.length)
                var first = parseInt(0)
                var last = parseInt(total-1)
                var prev = parseInt(total-2)

                var NuVaegt =  (splitWeight(lines[last],1))
                var StartVaegt = splitWeight(lines[first],1);
                var ForrigeVaegt = splitWeight(lines[prev],1)
                var Tabt = decimal((NuVaegt-StartVaegt),1)
                var Sidst = decimal((NuVaegt-ForrigeVaegt),1)
                return Tabt;


            });

       alert(Tabt) //function Kevin
       alert(Tabt) //function Heidi


        };//end getWeight
```

can you help me?

Please ignore this:
adding text
adding text

adding text

adding text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can't return data from an asynchronous function such as `$.get`, you have to use callbacks.
What you get back is deferred or promise objects which you can group like this:

```
var call1 = $.get(fileKevin...
var call2 = $.get(fileHeidi...

$.when( call1, call2 ).done(function ( txtKevin, txtHeidi ) {
```

checkout [$.when](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/)

you should probably refactor since you have duplicated code

example:

```
function getWeight() {

    var fileKevin = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/mytextfile1.txt";
    var fileHeidi = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/mytextfile1.txt";

    $.when(
        $.get(fileKevin),
        $.get(fileHeidi)
    ).done(function (txtKevin, txtHeidi) {
        var weightKevin = parseWeight(txtKevin),
            weightHeidi = parseWeight(txtHeidi);
        console.log(weightKevin, weightHeidi);
        // here you will call any function that has to use those values like:
        // doSomething(weightKevin, weightHeidi);
    });

    function parseWeight(txt) {
        var lines = txt.split("\n");

        var total = parseInt(lines.length)
        var first = parseInt(0)
        var last = parseInt(total-1)
        var prev = parseInt(total-2)

        var NuVaegt =  (splitWeight(lines[last],1))
        var StartVaegt = splitWeight(lines[first],1);
        var ForrigeVaegt = splitWeight(lines[prev],1)
        var Tabt = decimal((NuVaegt-StartVaegt),1)
        var Sidst = decimal((NuVaegt-ForrigeVaegt),1)
        return Tabt;
    }

};
```